Adding network address Keycloak Quay Container requires https
I want Keycloak to run using HTTP.  All works perfectly fine until I add the network section.
Here is my docker compose file:
services:
  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:22.0.1
    environment: 
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
    ports:
      - 8501:8080
    command: start-dev  
    networks:
      rbac_network:
        ipv4_address: 175.20.0.2

networks:
  rbac_network:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 175.20.0.0/16

The above will yield the message "HTTPS required"

If we remove the networks from docker compose then all works perfectly fine.  I can login.
What have I tried?
I've looked at different environment and start up parameters including
KC_HTTP_ENABLED: true
KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_HTTPS: false


You should delete the networks: blocks, especially if that solves your problem.  You should rarely if ever need to manually assign IP addresses to containers; Docker does this just fine on its own.  Furthermore, Compose also automatically creates a network named default for you.  For most Compose-based applications it's correct to have no networks: blocks at all in the entire file.
